# The homotopy theory presented by a Waldhausen category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Waldhausen introduced [his categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Waldhausen+category) for the purposes of defining algebraic $K$-theory of suitable categories. From a modern perspective, it looks like he was really doing two things at once:

1. Waldhausen categories look like a fancier version of relative categories: a way to present a homotopy theory (i.e. $\infty$-category). That is, given a Waldhausen category $(C,cof,W)$, there ought to be some $\infty$-functor 
   $$C \to Wald(C,cof,W)$$
   to a pointed, finitely-cocomplete $\infty$-category which universally turns the morphisms of $W$ into equivalences and pushouts along morphisms of $cof$ into homotopy pushouts, and preserves the $0$ object.

NB: As I'm defining it, $Wald(C,cof,W)$ depends on both $cof$ and $W$. It ought to be constructed as follows. Let $Psh_\ast(C)$ be the category of pointed $Top_\ast$-valued presheaves on $C$ and $y: C \to Psh_\ast(C)$ the Yoneda embedding. Let $S = y(W) \cup \{ yb \cup_{ya} yc \to y(b \cup_a c) \mid b \leftarrowtail a \to c \}$, and let $L_S Psh_\ast(C)$ be the localization at these morphisms. Then $Wald(C,cof,W) \subseteq L_S(Psh_\ast(C))$ is the closure of the representables under finite colimits.

2. Waldhausen $K$-theory appears to be an invariant associated to the $\infty$-category $Wald(C,cof,W)$, with a convenient presentation directly in terms of the data $(C,cof,W)$ via the $S_\bullet$ construction.

Now, I know of all sorts of ways to study the $\infty$-category presented by a category with weak equivalences $(C,W)$, depending on how nice $W$ is. And model categories give a way to study homotopy theory presented by similar data which includes cofibrations -- but it's well-known that in this case, the data of the cofibrations is redundant as far as the presented $\infty$-category goes, so that's a bit of a red herring. But what about when the Waldhausen category doesn't come from a model category?

**Question 1:** Has anybody studied the homotopy theory $Wald(C,cof,W)$ presented by a general Waldhausen category in the literature?

On the other hand, I know of several results in the literature showing that if one restricts to "nice" Waldhausen categories, the algebraic $K$-theory of the Waldhausen category is an invariant of its simplicial localization, and in particular the cofibrations are redundant for the purposes of $K$-theory. But in general, one would think that the cofibrations matter.

**Question 2:** Is it known in general whether Waldhausen $K$-theory is in fact an invariant of the $\infty$-category $Wald(C,cof,W)$ presented by a Waldhausen category $(C,cof,W)$?

**Question 3:** It's possible that I've been too naive in defining $Wald(C,cof,W)$. Should I perhaps consider something slightly different to be "the $\infty$-category presented by $(C,cof,W)$"?

Comment: Waldhausen categories are a ridiculously slick formalism solving a huge number of problems, like not having structured ring spectra. If you're trying to do $K$-theory, then, yeah, you should probably just work with ∞-categories. But Waldhausen was trying to relate $K$-theory to geometry. I think that there is a Waldhausen category where the equivalences are simple homotopy equivalences. The nerve of these equivalences is a space of interest. But it doesn't seem to be the maximal ∞-groupoid of an interesting (cocomplete) ∞-category.

Comment: I think the review of modern $K$-theory given by Robalo in [his thesis](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~marco.robalo/these.pdf) §7.1 is very well-done and might answer (positively) to most of your questions.

Comment: @BenWieland Good point. I'm confused about what lesson to draw. On the one hand, I might think that since simple homotopy equivalences don't satisfy 2/3, one shouldn't just localize at them. But then as you say, the space of simple homotopy equivalences is known to be interesting, so apparently it _is_ interesting to localize at them...

Comment: Regarding Question 2, I'm now skeptical that the answer should be affirmative unless $(C,cof,W)$ has the property that every morphism is weakly equivalent to a cofibration, which is essentially the type of hypothesis used to show the cofibrations don't matter in the literature... After all, the $S_\bullet$ construction cares which morphisms are "cofibrations".

Comment: Simple homotopy equivalences do satisfy 2/3. But inverting them them inverts all homotopy equivalences [see](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187278/is-there-a-category-whose-isomorphisms-are-precisely-the-simple-homotopy-equival)... A counterexample to 2 is that the category of finite sets is, technically, cocomplete as an $\infty$-category. If you take $S_\bullet$ for all morphisms you get zero, whereas $S_\bullet$ of monos is the sphere. But I'm not sure that this is really an interesting example; maybe one should just exclude it from the theory entirely.

Comment: @BenWieland I'm confused. On p. 327 of _Algebraic K-theory of Spaces_, Waldhausen gives the simple homotopy equivalences specifically as an example of weak equivalences which don't satisfy his "saturation axiom" (which is just 2/3).  I also don't see how what you're saying is a counterexample to (2) -- you give two examples of Waldhausen structures on $FinSet$ with different cofibrations, but in (2) I'm not asking whether $K$-theory is independent of $cof$ -- I'm asking whether it depends only on the $\infty$-category $Wald(C,cof,W)$, which depends on $cof$ as I've defined it.

Comment: I briefly commented previously and deleted it but Waldhausen's construction actually takes simple maps as weak equivalences. A simple map is a map where the preimage of any point has trivial Čech shape. Simple maps are simple homotopy equivalences and generate simple homotopy equivalences under zig-zags, but the definition of a simple homotopy equivalence actually gets messy and seems to be hard to work with. Simple maps do not satisfy 2/3, an example is $\Delta^0 \to \Delta^1 \to \Delta^0$. This is given in "SPACES OF PL MANIFOLDS AND CATEGORIES OF SIMPLE MAPS", look just after Prop'n 2.1.3

Comment: I actually started thinking about this a bit a few days ago. You can look at Blumberg-Gepner-Tabuada for a relationship between Waldhausen's $S_\bullet$ construction of $K$-theory and the $S_\bullet$ construction for $\infty$-categories, BUT as far as I can tell they need some assumptions on the Waldhausen category (namely DKHS-saturation) that don't hold for this particular Waldhausen category.

Comment: With some saturation assumption, as @JoeBerner writes in his comment, the $\infty$-category you denote by $Wald(C, \text{cof}, W)$ looks pretty much alike to what Toen-Vezzosi denote by M(C) in _A remark on $K$-theory and $S$-categories_ and to what Cisinski denotes by $\text{Ex}(C)$ in _Invariance de la $K$-théorie par équivalences dérivées_ (see in particular the last section; the definition is given in 4.10).

Comment: OK, but that just pushes around what the example of finite sets is a counterexample to. Your completion procedure expands it to finite cell complexes, which have a much larger $K$-theory.

Comment: @BenWieland Actually, I think the $K$-theory is the same, by Barratt-Priddy-Quillen. That is, $K(FinSet,Mono,Iso) = K(FinTop,\text{all maps},Iso) = \mathbb S$ (where $FinTop$ is the $\infty$-category of finite cell complexes, so its iso's are the weak homotopy equivalences; $\mathbb S$ is the sphere spectrum).

Comment: I see the confusion -- I didn't say _how_ to compute $K$-theory from a finitely-cocomplete infinity category. Implicitly, I'm thinking one should take the cofibrations to be all maps and then just apply the $S_\bullet$ construction.

Comment: No, the $K$-theory of finite complexes is the $K$-theory of finite spectra is $K(S)$ is big, rationally equivalent to $K(\mathbb Z)$. This shouldn't surprise you; this is exactly where you thought that the counterexample should be: not every map of finite sets is equivalent to a cofibration.

Comment: @BenWieland Ah, right -- I see now how confused I was! Thanks.